# NSDate and NSTimeZone wrong date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimezone

```
- (void)timeZoneChange
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.birthdate];

    NSDateFormatter* estDf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone2 = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [estDf setTimeZone:timeZone2];
    [estDf setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    self.timeZoneDate = [estDf dateFromString:dateString];
```

My problem : I take *self.birthdate* from user and I change to *dateString* in his TimeZone. I need to save changed date into CD as NSDate so I changing StringToDate with SystemTimeZone and self.timeZoneDate returns UTC date not in systemTimeZone.

Example *self.birthdate* = 27.04.2005 then *self.timeZoneDate* = 26.04.2005 22:00:00  +0000. I now [NSDate date] = UTC time  but is any trick ? I need *self.timeZoneDate* as date in systemTimeZone

Comment: There is absolutely no reason you need to convert an `NSDate` to another `NSDate` to make any sort of timezone adjustment. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Because I got NSDate and i dont know how to change NSDate timezone without change first to string.

Comment: `NSDate` **does not have a time zone**, so there is no way to change its time zone.

Comment: @AmdxRux I asked why you think you need to change the date's timezone. What is your goal? The only time a timezone is relevant is when you need to create a string from the date to display it to the user.

Comment: So i got NSDate from DatePicker. I want to adjust this date to user device date and save to DB. I dont want situation when user birthday's are example 2.02.2016 but in DB will be 1.02:2016 22:00:00

Comment: NSDate represents an instant in time on planet Earth. It does not have a time zone. When a user inputs a date into a date picker, he will express that date in his local time zone, but when you ask the picker for the date that the user selected, it will give it back to you as an `NSDate` that is not specific to a time zone. If you then use a date formatter to display that date, it will be displayed in the  time zone of the date output date formatter